# What should I do with a question that I can't get an answer for?

Tags: discussion, bounties, unanswered-questions

[Why am I getting a "well-formedness constraint: unique attribute spec" (0xc00cee3c) error when I descend from LongListSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880464/why-am-i-getting-a-well-formedness-constraint-unique-attribute-spec-error-when)

No answers. Some non-answers in comments that don't actually answer the question, but might be worth a shot. I'd like an answer to this question.

I've already tried a bounty, and got . . . zero answers.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I'd consider putting the error code in the title, but I don't see any problems with it that would turn people away.  Lance is probably right that no one knows.

Comment: Call Microsoft Support.  Have your credit card ready.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### General Observations / Introduction

The Drake equation for the number of answers to your question is:

N =
R*·
f<sub>a</sub>·
n<sub>a</sub>·
f<sub>k</sub>·
f<sub>v</sub>·
f<sub>m</sub>·
L

where:

- **R*** is the number of users on Stack Overflow
- **f<sub>a</sub>** is the percentage of these users who answer questions
- **n<sub>a</sub>** is the average number of answers posted by each of these users
- **f<sub>k</sub>** is the fraction of those answerers who have knowledge in the subject of your question
- **f<sub>v</sub>** is the fraction of those answerers who visit your question
- **f<sub>m</sub>** is the fraction of those answerers who feel motivated to answer your question
- **L** is the amount of time your answer spends on the front page

There is also a fraction of users who follow tags religiously, who randomly probe the archives via Google or the search, or actively search out other unanswered questions, but these are, in my experience, far less numerous than those who simply watch the front page.  Consider these the equivalent of supernatural intervention.

You have very little control over most of the factors involved in creating answers to your questions.  The only factors you can affect are **f<sub>m</sub>** and **L**.  Motivate users to answer your question with a demonstration of effort, good copy, quick feedback to comments, rep through bounties, and a promise of an accepted answer through frequent visits and a high accept rate.

### Practical Information

In your case, A +50 bounty didn't do much more than bring your question to the bottom of the "featured" tab and a slight increase in the number of views.  That said, I've dropped +300 bounties on questions which haven't gotten an answer before.  ([This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13041/how-do-i-make-the-fairchild-fsa9280-fsa9480-fsa880-boot-pin-trigger-samsung-gal) is the question, it requires access to a certain group of Samsung phones and/or a proprietary datasheet which is probably under an NDA.)  Your question requires a knowledge of both Silverlight and Windows Phone 7, which restricts your audience severely.

Also, the question had no upvotes.  I realize this is mostly beyond your control, but upvotes will help your question get more readership.  0-voted questions are all too often poorly formatted questions on their way to downvotes, while a highly voted question with no answers is just begging for an answer to be added and share in the upvotes that the question is getting.  I'm not a Silverlight or WP7 dev, so I'm not super qualified, but it seemed useful and clear to me so I upvoted it as a start.

One other thing that you should have done/should do is to edit your question as you improve your code and invalidate possible solutions.  This has two beneficial effects: It demonstrates that you're actively pursuing the solution yourself and are still engaged in the process, and every edit will bump the question to the top of the "active" tab, where a lot of eyes are looking.

Comment: So, thanks for this information. You mentioned editing my question as I worked on it. I've been wanting to make this particular control, and this is basically what I wanted, so I started along this route, and I got stuck here. After tweaking a few things, but still being unable to progress, I hacked around it, so my code works, because I needed to deliver, but it's an ugly solution (much uglier than what Nigel presented), so I hope for the day when I can get around this bug and put it back in. I guess I should be working on it more. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you've edited everything you can into the question, and a bounty drew a blank, then there probably isn't the knowledge base on this site to answer that question.  You'll need to look elsewhere.  I've got some that can't be answered also; there are tough questions out there.